# UIButton subclass is changing font on click

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am seeing some weird behavior from an array of buttons I have built in storyboard. I have 4 buttons each of custom type `TakesContainerButton` and when a button is clicked it changes to the system font, but when a different button is clicked the previously button returns to the desired font, not sure what is going on here

The buttons are also embedded in a stack view, if that matters

Here is the the implementation when one of the buttons is pressed where `buttons` is an array of the 4 buttons

```
@IBAction func filterPressed(_ sender: TakesContainerButton) {
        for button in buttons {
            button.unclick()
        }
        sender.click()
    }
```

here is the custom class

```
class TakesContainerButton: UIButton {

        
        var bottom = UIView()
        
        func click(){
            self.setTitleColor(.darkGray, for: .normal)
            let xOffset:CGFloat = 10
            bottom = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: xOffset / 2, y: self.frame.height - 3, width: self.frame.width - xOffset, height: 3))
            bottom.layer.cornerRadius = 1.5
            bottom.backgroundColor = .darkGray
            self.addSubview(bottom)
        }
        
        func unclick(){
            bottom.removeFromSuperview()
            self.setTitleColor(UIColor(hex: "8B8B8B"), for: .normal)
        }
        
        override func awakeFromNib(){
            setFont()
        }
        
        func setFont(){
            self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Bold", size: 12)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In StoryBoard set button :

Type to Custom

Style to Default and

State Config to Default

you should have something like this

[image]

Comment: you're welcome, and happy new year!, by the way I didn't find how to do the same programmatically, please let me know if you find it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason that you are calling setFont() on every click. As I am able to see that you are not changing the font you should set this font at the time of view loading and leave the font as it is.

Comment: Originally It was only in awakeFromNib, but I was experiencing that issue so I put it in both click and unclick

Comment: You don't need to set font every time.