# Button text color won't change with setTitleColor

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uibutton

I can not seem to get the text in two of my buttons to change to white, unless I manually do it through the storyboard. Any ideas?

```swift
class AppUIButton: UIButton {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
        backgroundColor = Theme.tintColor
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2
        setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    }
}


class AddTripViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tripTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cencelButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIButton!
    
    var doneSaving: (() -> ())?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: Theme.mainFontName, size: 24)
        
        //I can force the text color to change with the bellow
        //cencelButton.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
        //cencelButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        
        //saveButton.setTitle("Add", for: .normal)
        //saveButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
       
    }
    
    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
    
    @IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
        TripFunctions.createTrip(tripModel: TripModel(title: tripTextField.text!))
        if let doneSaving = doneSaving {
            doneSaving()
        }
        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: bro you have created a custom class AppUIButton but you haven't used it your IBOutlets are of type UIBUtton so there will be no change if you use UIButton instead of AppUIButton

Comment: I have selected both of the buttons on the view controller and set the class as the "AppUIButton". All of the other attributes I have set in the custom class are being applied, the background color & rounded corners, just not the text color.

Comment: @JoelKellogg - it's working fine for me... Are you running some other code that might be affecting it? Do you have the same problem if you create a new view controller, add a button, set its class to `AppUIButton` and display it with no `@IBOutlet` connections?

Comment: @DonMag That was a good idea, I went ahead and did as you suggested and created a new button. However, I am getting the same result. It applies all attributes but doesn't change text color. I have manually set the tint to a green color so I can easily tell if the text changes to white. Could this be affecting it?

Comment: In Storyboard, are you changing the button `Type` from `System` to something else? Are you changing the `Style` from `Plain` to something else? What if you **don't** "manually set the tint"? Again, though, it's working fine for me... Is it possible you have some `UIButton` extension somewhere? Have you tried it with a new Project, adding **only** your `AppUIButton` class (changing `Theme.tintColor` to a plain `UIColor`)?

Answer (score 1):

If you had created that button in the storyboard. Just go to that button's attribute inspector in storyboard and make sure

**1. Button Type is Custom**

**2. Button Style is Default**

[image]

Note : this will also resolve's the issue of button font getting set to system font on tap. Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70088481/uibutton-subclass-is-changing-font-on-click/74420034#74420034) for reference.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create a custom class for UIButton you can do something like this

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class ThemeButton: UIButton {

     
    @IBInspectable var borderRadius:CGFloat = 10.0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.borderRadius
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var fontSize:CGFloat = 14 {
        didSet {
            self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.ThemeRegular(ofSize: fontSize)
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setUI()
        //        self.isSelected = true
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUI()
    }
    
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        setUI()
    }
    
    private func setUI() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.clipsToBounds = true
            self.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
            self.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.ThemeRegular(ofSize: self.fontSize)
            self.backgorundColor = .red
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.borderRadius
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use it by giving your button class name to the UIButton

[image]

Comment: This is actually what I did above, with no luck. All of the other attributes are applying, just not the text color.

Comment: @JoelKellogg please Check your IBOutlet Class they are not of you custom class type

Comment: @JoelKellogg you can copy-paste my code and follow the steps as shown yo may achieve your goal

Comment: please see image and press enter after giving custom class

Answer (score -2):

This should work for you.

```
titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: this did not work either unfortunately :(